# ¿ como ejecutar llamar un url con autenticación desde una api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Buen día

Estoy programando el siguiente método y estoy buscando la forma de ejecutar un url que me devuelve un archivo pero es necesario que le pase datos de autenticación para que me pueda devolver el archivo:

```
        [Route("[controller]/ObtenerDocumentoById")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SeleccionaDocumentoById(string objectId)
        {
            var username = "usuario";
            var password = "mypass";

            var authInfo = username + ":" + password;
            var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));

            var requestURL = "https://ct-cc-b01d/portal/jsp/eDocument?operation=getDocument&snapsId=2344.35af1-ff04a-4f92-944-006fe49ab777&ServerConfigurationName=EB_ESM_SERVER&documentId=idd_CC4C7E68-6A05";

HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
            using (var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler)) {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(requestURL);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
 
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",encoded);

                var result = await client.GetAsync(requestURL);

                var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                
                return Ok();


        }
```

Mi primera duda es como ejecutar la url y la segunda es como pasarle los datos de autenticación para que se pueda ejecutar correctamente y por ultimo que tipo de retorno debo tener para regresar el archivo.

Agradezco de antemano el apoyo.

Comment: A que url es que debes de enviarle el parametro de autenticacion?

Comment: La url es la que tengo declarada com requestURL. Gracias

Comment: falta informacion.. como recibe el usuario y pass la url? a que te referis con ejecutar la url? si te devuelve un archivo, tenes que andar leyendo la respuesta hasta que esta termine...

Comment: Es que la url forma parte de otra aplicación, entonces si yo ejecuto en el navegador la url me devuelve el archivo siempre y cuando este autenticado en la aplicación. Por eso es que estoy manejando dos variables que almacenaran las credenciales, es decir el Usuario y la contraseña.  Entonces este metodo lo tengo que llamar desde otra app para que puede yo descargar el archivo.

Comment: el unico parámetro que debo recibir es el id del documento y pasarlo a la url.

Comment: Me late que debes pasar por un header el bearer token, ¿tienes la documentación de la api con la que te conectas?

Comment: Es que es un metodo que ya funciona, pero no tengo acceso a la api ni a la documentación. Solo se que esa url de acceso al método funciona pero si estoy autenticado en la aplicación que hace uso de el, por eso es que requiero pasarle dos datos de autenticación para que me devuelva el archivo.

Comment: En ese caso, F12 y mira las peticiones, ¿le pasa algún header con un token? ¿cómo se genera ese token? Si no se sabe, por más que tengas usuario y clave, ¿cómo validarías que ese token funcione?

Comment: Otra opción es que utilicen una cookie de autenticación, y ahi el escenario sería obtener esa cookie y pasarle esa cookie en la petición :D

Comment: ¿ como puedo obtener y recibir esa cookie de autenticación ?me suena muy interesante

Comment: Acabo de actualizar el código, sin embargo ¿ como debo recibir o retornar el archivo ya que observando solo veo que me regresa un html  y deberia yo recibir un pdf ?